# Add external library by source to an existing project using android studio

Tags: java, android

How can i add an existing library, checked out from github, to my project without copying it into the modules directory?

For example i have checked out zxing and tried to add it to my project, but i can't find how to do it.
Since i want to patch zxing for portrait mode, i need to add/compile the sources. The maven-version was easy to implement (just add compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0' as dependencies), but how to do it with source?

I have that structure:

```
Projects\
    MyApp\MyModule\ ..
    zxing\core\ ...
```

Thank you in advance,
Juergen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in two ways.

**First method**

Import source of the library to Android Studio as a separate project. After that, build project to `*.jar` or `*.aar` file, then copy it to `lib` directory of your project and add dependency to libraries from this directory in your project.

**Second method**

Import sources of the library to your project in a separate module. After that, add dependency to this module in module of your app.

When you perform one of these actions, you should be able to use library in your project.

Nevertheless, if library you want to use is available on Maven Central Repository, I recommend you to use Maven or Gradle build system and add it as a dependency. Methods mentioned above should be used, when your library is custom and not available on Maven Central Repository.

Comment: Thank you, first method seems to be the easiest. Just to pull the code, compile it and add it as a library. In that case i can't use maven because i will to do some changes to the code (portrait mode for zxing scanner).